# SWT BrowserFunction not registering

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, browser, swt

I have a Java SWT application using several Browser widgets to display html documents. Those html documents have some javascript code that communicates with the Java code through BrowserFunction instances. It used to work like charm for quite a long time, until suddenly it started being messy : the problem seems to be that the BrowserFunction doesn't get properly registered/attached to the Browser anymore.

I suspect something went wrong with some SWT dependency, since I didn't change anything in my code, nor did I change SWT version, the library itself. Indeed when I made a fresh-install of my Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) and ran my program BEFORE running any updates : it worked as expected. I then ran 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade', after that the problem appeared again.

Below is a code snippet reproducing the problem :`

**Expected behaviour** : clicking the "create a browser" button creates a Browser widget, loads 'test.html'. Then, clicking the 'click here' link calls a Java function from Javascript through a BrowserFunction instance, and prints something out to the Java console. You should be able to click "create a browser" button several times and have multiple Browser widgets created with that "click here" link working.

**Actual behaviour** : the "click here" link only works in the first Browser widget you create. From the second on, the widget is still created, the html page still loads, but the "click here" link prompts the following javascript error : "Can't find variable : callJavaFunction".

**Configuration** : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (tried also under 18.04 with the same result), openjdk 11.0.11, swt.jar version 4.924 (tried also with the latest 4.942 with the same result)

**Other things I've tried** : uninstalling libwebkitgtk-1.0-0, reinstalling it, installing libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 instead, using a Wayland session as opposed to Xorg, using Unity desktop, using Mate desktop.

Again, I managed to get it to work on a newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 BEFORE any updates were made and without installing anything other than Java. Then, running OS updates made the problem appear again. I spent hours browsing the web about that, but I really struggle to understand all this Webkit and GTK stuff.

So here goes the code :

public class TestWindow extends Composite {

```
int y = 0;

TestWindow(Shell shell) {
    
    super(shell,SWT.BORDER);

    this.setSize(600,700);
    
    Button button = new Button(this,SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Create a browser");
    button.setLocation(200,650);
    button.pack();
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            createBrowser();
        }
        
    });

}

public void createBrowser() {
    System.out.println("\nCreate a new browser");
    
    Browser browser = new Browser(this,SWT.BORDER);
    browser.setSize(500,200);
    browser.setLocation(0,y);
    
    File htmlFile = new File("test.html");
    browser.setUrl(htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
    
    final BrowserFunction brf = new JavaFunction(browser, "callJavaFunction");
    
    y = y + 200;
}

private static class JavaFunction extends BrowserFunction {
    String name;
    JavaFunction(Browser browser, String name) {
        super(browser, name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object function(Object[] arguments) {
        System.out.println("Java called from Javascript");
        if (name.equals("callJavaFunction")) {
            System.out.println("function callJava with argument : "+arguments[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}`

The code in 'test.html' is the following

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(msg){
    try {
        callJavaFunction(msg);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<a href="javascript:hello('link clicked')">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

...

My Main class is the following :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Test");
        TestWindow testWindow = new TestWindow(shell);
        
        shell.setSize(600,700);
      
       shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
          }
        }
        display.dispose();

}
```

}

Many thanks in advance to anyone who could shed some light on this...

Comment: You probably need to report this on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/), I can't see any obvious existing report of such a problem.

Comment: @greg-449 : Thanks for your suggestion. I have now found, if not a solution, at least a workaround, I'm posting it below.

Answer (score 1):

So, I dug into my updates history and found out that the following 4 packages are causing the problem. Downgrading them makes BrowserFunction work again :

- libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
- libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
- gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
- gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0

A recent upgrade from version 2.30.6 to version 2.32.0 is the cause of the problem.
For some reason, I couldn't revert to 2.30.6 since it doesn't appear to be available in the repositories, but I could downgrade to version 2.28.1, which did the trick : sudo apt install PACKAGE_NAME=2.28.1-1

Then, I used the following command to prevent those packages from being updated again : echo "PACKAGE_NAME hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

I wrote the following bash script to take care of it after every fresh install on every machine where I use my program :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Downgrading the 4 packages to version 2.28.1-1..."

    sudo apt install libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18=2.28.1-1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37=2.28.1-1 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0=2.28.1-1 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0=2.28.1-1

    echo ""
    echo "Keeping those 4 packages from upgrading again..."

    echo "libwebkit2gtk" && echo "libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    echo "libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18" && echo "libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    echo "gir1.2-webkit2-4.0" && echo "gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
    echo "gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0" && echo "gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

    echo ""
    echo "Checking installed versions :"

    echo "libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37" && dpkg -s libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 | grep Version
    echo "libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18" && dpkg -s libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 | grep Version
    echo "gir1.2-webkit2-4.0" && dpkg -s gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 | grep Version
    echo "gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0" && dpkg -s gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 | grep Version

    echo ""
    echo "Checking packages marked as 'held' from future upgrades"
    dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

    echo ""
    echo "done"
```

This is a workable solution only as long as those previous versions are still available on the repos, which one can assume should be the case for the forseable future. Still, they will eventually disappear, making it unsustainable in the long run.

I'm not sure whether that can qualify as a bug per say in Eclipse SWT, but it seems nonetheless important to flag the issue to them. I'm therefore going to follow greg's suggestion and file a report in Eclipse Bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks for your research and command. Ultimately, this command worked for me on Debian `sudo apt install libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18=2.18.6-1~deb9u1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37=2.18.6-1~deb9u1 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0=2.18.6-1~deb9u1 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0=2.18.6-1~deb9u1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0=1.10.4-1 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0=1.10.4-1+deb9u1 libgstreamer1.0-0=1.10.4-1` but while it fixed the issue you mention, it created collateral issues such as webpages that don't open anymore with firefox. So I have to revert back for now and hope it gets fixed in a next version :-(

Comment: I can see you had to downgrade also libgstreamer, apart from the 4 packages I mentionned ?

Comment: The bug I filed can be followed here, it has generated some follow-up  :https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=573616

Comment: Correct, I had to downgrade libgstreamer because Debian was rejecting the downgrade otherwise.

Thanks for opening a bug, I will follow that closely

Comment: I confirm that this issue is fixed in Eclipse 22.6.0